# Bash script to check if process is running and read user input to start if necessary

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having a problem with using `nohup` in a script. The script works properly if `nohup` is not used
to start the process. The following error is received when run:

```
./iper.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./iper.sh: line 16: `        [Yy]*) nohup iperf -s > /dev/null 2>&1&; break;;'
```

Here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "Checking to see if Iperf is running:"
sleep 2

ps cax | grep iperf > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Iperf is running."
else
    echo "Iperf is not running." 
fi
sleep 2

while true; do
    read -p "Press Y to start Iperf or N to exit: " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]*) nohup iperf -s > /dev/null 2>&1&; break;;
        [Nn]*) exit;; 
    esac
done
```

What is happening?

Comment: The script doesn't complete, if I do not use the nohup, the script will run. My goal would be to start Iperf but have it run in the background and keep running when I logout.

Comment: Just curious as why you edited my post without commenting on it first?  I believe I explained what is happening clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to terminate your command with `&` to put it to background, do not terminate it with another semicolon `;` as well:

```
[Yy]*) nohup iperf -s > /dev/null 2>&1& break;;
```

Previously

```
2>&1&;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It now works as I hoped. I should have caught that since the error message directly explained the problem. I can't vote your answer up unfortunately as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have an extra `&` in `2>&1&`

Change it to `2>&1`

Comment: The extra & is so control c is not needed, I didn't want to have to use any extra input. If I leave the extra & off the script starts Iperf but the script does't finish to allow user input on the shell.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Check with below script

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "Checking to see if Iperf is running:"
sleep 1

if  `pgrep iperf >/dev/null 2>&1`
then
    echo "iperf Running"
else
    echo "iperf not Running"
fi

sleep 1

while true; do
        echo "Do you wanna start Iperf (y/n)"
        read  -n 1 ch; p=`echo ${ch} | tr A-Z a-z`
        case $p in
                y)nohup iperf -s > /dev/null 2>&1 break;;

                n)exit;;

                *)continue;
    esac
done
```

when this been executed it waits for user to press**ctrl + c** to come out

if you are using 2>&1&(for continuing without user interference)allowing user to do other work

replace below line in y) condition

```
nohup iperf -s > /dev/null 2>&1& break;;
```